# Can this minor style error be fixed?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]
One user is slightly lower than the others. Can we get a fix for this? The page is
https://english.stackexchange.com/about.

Comment: [All mods are equal, but some mods are more equal than others](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/all-mods-are-equal-but-some-mods-are-more-equal-than-others). Not sure if I should reopen that one, because this time the reason is a bit different, even though the observed effect is basically the same.

Comment: Now you cannot say it's because the badges. `:-)`

Comment: It's just because waiwai wasn't elected. Normally they put an "Appointed YYYY" note there, but maybe someone forgot.

Comment: @mmy he was elected in the sense that he finished 4th in the election.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have added the public artifacts to this appointment.